# Opposite of "specialized" in the context of computing units

Tags: antonyms, computing

A graphics card or an algebraic co-processor is a **specialized** computing unit.

A conventional CPU, which understands a lot more instructions, is a **flexible** computing unit.

I'm not happy with using **flexible** in the second sentence.

What are other possibilities?

Comment: General-purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[General](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/general#Adjective)* (“Not limited in use or application; applicable to the whole or every member of a class or category”) is suitable, as in  “A conventional CPU is a general [or general purpose] computing unit.”

Note that having “a lot more instructions” is not what makes a processing unit general-purpose; for example, [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC) (reduced instruction set computing) processors may have a sharply limited set of instructions but are still general purpose, while a [CISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing) [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) can have quite a few more different instructions but be capable only of specialized processing.  (Of course, there are also numerous GPU's that are [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units)s, capable of general purpose computing.)  Thus, the original statement about specialized vs general processors is overly simplistic.